# collection is not associated with any session

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-session

Can anyone help me with this exception, tried every way mentioned online but still it is getting failed in the server. This is to find all user with pagination based on the specs. pasting the exception for your reference.

```
Exception (UserServiceImpl.getUserList) : collection is not associated with any session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: collection is not associated with any session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:500) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:217) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.prj.um.core.imp.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.getUserList(UserServiceImpl.java:1123) ~[user-management-core-0.0.1.jar:?]
    at com.prj.um.core.imp.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.search(UserServiceImpl.java:1070) ~[user-management-core-0.0.1.jar:?]
    at com.prj.um.core.imp.services.impl.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a79c3a79.invoke(<generated>) ~[user-management-core-0.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) [spring-tx-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) [spring-tx-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) [spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) [spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.prj.um.core.imp.services.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a52fd71e.search(<generated>) [user-management-core-0.0.1.jar:?]
    at com.prj.um.core.imp.controller.UserController.search(UserController.java:208) [user-management-core-0.0.1.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) [spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) [wildfly-undertow-10.1.0.Final.jar!/:10.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) [undertow-core-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) [wildfly-undertow-10.1.0.Final.jar!/:10.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104) [undertow-servlet-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202) [undertow-core-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805) [undertow-core-1.4.0.Final.jar!/:1.4.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_232]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:678) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:890) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.readPage(SimpleJpaRepository.java:569) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:388) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:610) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:573) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:554) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 76 more
```

if you are wondering what is in line number 1123

> Page persons = userSpecification.findAll(personSpec, page);

Yes the getUserList function has `@Transactional`

Hoping someone could find the problem. Thanks

Comment: Huh, that's funny. It would seem Hibernate is trying to initialize an eagerly-loaded collection after the session has already been closed. Is there a collection with `fetch = EAGER` in your entity? If so, does it work when you switch to `LAZY`?

Comment: Thanks for the Reply @crizzis, Nice question. Yes I'd 3 EAGER fetch collection. Its working even when i change it to LAZY, but in the server its not working.

Comment: Do you mean it's working in embedded server mode, but not when you deploy to Undertow? I never used it, but from the symptoms you describe, it would seem transactions are somehow misconfigured, and there's something weird going on with the transaction boundaries

Comment: `@crizzis`, after changing `EAGER` to `LAZY` and then clearing the cache, this issue got fixed. But still not getting why it is happening. Your answer helped. Thanks for the answer. But can you state why it is happening?

Comment: You can override the annotation level settings using query options and fetch groups. Specify something shouldn't be fetched (or exclude it from an otherwise very inclusive fetch group) and that should make the relationship behave as if it was lazy.

Comment: You mentioned "clearing the cache". What kind of cache are you talking about here?